# How to use multiple OIDC clients with a single realm in Quarkus (IDP: Keycloak). Multi-tenancy support with Token instead of RoutingContext's path

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

I have two questions regarding the use of OIDC with Keycloak in Quarkus:

1. I need to use multiple clients with a single realm (tenant). How to?
2. Right now, multi-tenancy is based on `RoutingContext`'s path parameter. What if I want to use the same API URL path for multiple tenants/realms? In that case, I will have to use JWT Token's "issuer" parameter to distinguish the realm. Is there a way to get the JWT Token in the `TenantResolver`? I can't see the Authorization header in the header properties of the 'RoutingContext'.

Here, if the second issue is solved, then the first one can also be resolved by implementing `TenantResolver`, and using the token's "authorized party" parameter.

In my app, I have a single realm with multiple clients. The API URL paths are pretty complex and some have common paths associated with. If I go by separating the realm, I can't distinguish the realm using the API URL path. If there is a way to get the token in the `TenantResolver`, then I could either use "one realm, multiple clients" or "multiple realms, single/multiple clients" configuration. But I don't prefer to separate the realm. So how can I deal with this situation?. I really need to use multiple clients with the same single realm.

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11021